# What is the maximum number of non-overlapping interior regions?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

**Problem**

> What is the maximum number of non-overlapping interior regions that can be created by four chords of a circle?

**Attempt**

I tried drawing a figure with the most number of regions I could try to make and got $10$ but the answer is $11$. How do I solve this with certainty?

Edit: How does one prove that $11$ is the maximum?

Comment: What does "created" mean here?

Comment: @ChrisCulter I think formed is a better word.

Comment: look at the wiki entry for [lazy caterer's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence) and the refs there.